# How to search and replace a particular code line in C source using Perl/anything else?

Tags: c, perl, replace

I have a C source code spread over many source files (*.c). For porting reasons say I need to comment out below statements from all source files

```
fprintf(stderr,"......",....);
```

The problem is these fprintfs could be multiline statements, meaning broken into two/or more lines spread over two lines in source files with a newline character(carriage returned entered at end of one line).

How can I find such fprintfs scattered across all source files, replace them with a 
multiline C comment as:

```
/*
*/
```

Since they are multiline, the find and replace command of source editors did not help.

I am trying to read the source file using a PERL script but, parse them to do this but could not.

Any pointers would be useful.

thank you.
-AD.

Comment: You can also try [M4 preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(language))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just

```
#undef fprintf
#define fprintf(stream, format, ...) 42
```

at the top of your files and be happy.

Comment: @goldenmean: `fprintf` returns an `int` (for the number of characters written; or negative in case of error). I thought it would be better to `#define` the function for an `int` and simply erase all side-effects (instead of simply removing it). As for `42` in particular, I think any positive integer (not 0) would be ok; and 42 is a good one.

Comment: @pmg: Ok so this macro would replace every occurence of fprintf(..); with 42; Just curious why not 0; what would happen if the macro has 0 or some -ve number defined. Anyway fprintf is being replaced completely by another number, I don't thing that number needs to be +ve or something. Am  i correct?

Comment: @goldenmean: I don't think anybody ever uses the return value of `printf` for anything. Just covering the eventual over zealous programmer: `if (printf("%d\n", foo) < 0) exit(PRINTF_ERROR);`. In the absence of any such test (the usual) any integer (or nothing) is just as good.

Comment: Problem with this is that it will substitute every fprintf, not only fprinting to stderr, which may or may not be problem. (if the program use fprintf for some file IO, this define will break it)

Comment: "I don't think anybody ever uses the return value of printf for anything." - value is vitally important in some applications which need to know how many bytes were output.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is named "coccinelle", it's semantic patch tool for C, via this you can easily do this. viz. http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/

Answer (score 0):

For a pure perl solution try something like this:

```
my $all_lines;
{              # (limit scope of $/, if appropriate)
  local $/;    #slurp entire file in one go
  $all_lines = <$file_handle>
  $all_lines =~ s|(\bfprintf\s*\(\s*stderr\s*,.*?\)\s*;)|/* $1 */|sg;
}
```